# how to locate images inside card

Tags: flutter, widget, position

We need to put few images inside a circler card.
each time we choose randomly:few images to each image we choose randomly it's size and angle.
we tried to do this with 'Stack widget' and 'positined' but the images go beyond the card.
we want to know if there is another way to create this (with another widgets) ?
or if our method is good how to improve it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Double(),
    );
  }
}

class Double extends StatefulWidget {
  const Double({super.key});

  @override
  State<Double> createState() => _Double();
}

class _Double extends State<Double> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 220, 180, 126),
        ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/images/back.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text(
                "Click on the only symbol on the right card that matches the symbol on the left card:",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 15,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 400,
                        width: 400,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                        child: Stack(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Positioned(
                              left: 200,
                              top: 10,
                              child: SizedBox(
                                height: 70,
                                child: RotatedBox(
                                  quarterTurns: 18,
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    "assets/images/demostar.png",
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                              right: 200,
                              bottom: 50,
                              child: SizedBox(
                                height: 160,
                                child: RotatedBox(
                                  quarterTurns: 0,
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    "assets/images/demostar.png",
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                              right: 250,
                              bottom: 200,
                              child: SizedBox(
                                height: 130,
                                child: RotatedBox(
                                  quarterTurns: 23,
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    "assets/images/demostar.png",
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 400,
                        width: 400,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 15,
                      ),
                    ]),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: try `CustomMultiChildLayout`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.